# push td to the right without extra markup

Tags: html, css

How to push the second row's td to the right? I know I can simply add one more empty `td` but I want to produce cleaner markup. Is there any css attribute to avoid that?

```html
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Add a `colspan ='2'`?

Comment: I think an empty `td` is appropriate here and wouldn't really violate the concept of _"cleaner"_ markup, only a concept of _"less"_ markup. You have two columns with clearly defined labels/headers. When I look at your markup (only) I'm thinking the month is $100, which is counter-intuitive and a mistake made by the author. With an empty `td` I can assume there is a reason it is empty like possibly continuing data for the previously provided month without having to say said month for every single row. The empty `td` also places the second `$100` `td` into proper context/column.

Comment: Besides, what do you mean by cleaner markup? Seeing an empty `<td></td>` is more intuitive than any other sort of CSS magic

Comment: If you just want to align text to right then you can use nth-child CSS3 selector. https://jsfiddle.net/qy16rntp/

Comment: @hungerstar I agree absolutely. *cleaner* markup is an empty td

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a pseudo element, like this, CSS only, no change in the markup

What happens here is that when the pseudo renders it will render as an anonymous table cell, hence push the existing one to the right in the same way the `<td></td>` markup would.

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table tr:nth-child(3):before {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This could be [converted to a reusable class](https://jsfiddle.net/1gegam7u/): `.shim:before { content: ''; }`. Then apply to each `tr` that needs a `td` shimmed to the right. Though I personally feel an empty `td` is the appropriate choice.

Comment: @hungerstar Yes, one can (and it is a good idea), if one want to add that class into the markup .. and I agree using the empty `td`, easier to read the markup/code flow.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to produce the extra `<td></td>` before the $100 cell. If you insist on not using the extra `<td></td>`, try `<td colspan="2" style="text-align:right;">$100</td>`

Comment: Thanks for consolidating all the answers that were already shared in the comments

Comment: No problem @EatPeanutButter didn't refresh until after I posted.