# align td width joining multiple tables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This might sounds stupid, but I have to accept that I couldn't change the html markup. 
How can I push LA and 2015 to the right and the width is the same with the table's td above? Like LA should under Havard and 2015 should under 2015. The challenge here is I have 2 tables.

I think of using Javascript but want to know what's the alternative.

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>James</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>Havard</td>
    <td>2016</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  
  <table>
  <tr>
    
    <td>LA</td>
    <td>2015</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is basically the same question you asked earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258583/push-td-to-the-right-without-extra-markup

Comment: @EatPeanutButter no, the previous one is easy because it's single table.

Comment: @JamieJordan Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I can try javascript approach. Just get and set the width but I would like to see whether can I avoid using any js or not.

Comment: What if you create 2 extra `<td>` cells to the left of LA and 2015 and just have them be blank, and then use inline style to remove the borders from those cells? This way it's completely blank and looks like nothing is there at all, so the cells LA and 2015 will be pushed to the right?

Comment: @JamieJordan if you cannot use javascript how do you plan on changing the page? PHP?

Comment: No alternative, in this case - use javascript.

Comment: @JoeL you don't understand my question at all

Comment: @JamieJordan yup I apparently completely misunderstood it. So above, now I'm reading it again and interpreting it as you want LA and 2015 to be on the right, but also for LA's width to be the same as Harvard's cell, and the same for 2015 & 2016. If I'm getting it right now, I am in agreement that Javascript is the choice that should be made.

Comment: I am not understanding, Why you can't change HTML markup